# Problem while installing amd driver on ubuntu 12.10 on my dell inspiron 5520

Tags: drivers, video

I have a dell inspiron 5520 which has switchable graphics mode with amd radeon hd 7600m.
I have recently installed ubuntu 12.10 alongside windows.
But i can't install the driver for grahics card.
While typing "sudo apt-get install fglrx-installer" it says unable to locate the package.
While adding the repository ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates it shows error that

```
"The requested URL /ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-         i386/Packages was not found on this server."
```

In another attempt i download driver from amd-driver site, and then installing from terminal it shows that some errors come while installing and I get the blank screen only.

So how to install the amd driver on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I had what seems to be the same issue.  The AMD driver needs to be downgraded.  Follow the steps here: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal.html

This will install the legacy driver which may (if it is the same problem) bring things back to full resolution again.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try update? I had Dell Inspiron N5030 two years ago and I had a problem with graphic cards driver... I updated my system, rebooted and it was OK.